# J2me textfields layout

Tags: layout, java-me, textfield

I have 3 textfields for a date in a midlet(in order to combine dots and numbers). Two of them accept 2 digits, that last one 4 digits(year). How can I place them into one row? 
EDIT: maybe there's some kind of container for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution - every textfield should have layout Item.LAYOUT_2